How does the choice of optimization algorithm change the quality of the results?
Take the normal distribution:
$$f(x|\mu,\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$
It is well known that the MLE will produce a biased estimate of the variance. This is because the MLE estimate of the variance relies on the MLE estimate of the mean, thus resulting in a form of error propagation. However, the MLE of the mean is not biased because it only relies on the data:
$$\hat{\mu}_{\text{MLE}} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$
$$\hat{\sigma}^2_{\text{MLE}} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \hat{\mu})^2$$
We can correct this bias manually to ensure that the expected value is equal to the actual value:
$$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \hat{\mu})^2$$
$$E[s^2] = \sigma^2$$
This exact correction is not always possible in actual applications, therefore we use complex methods like RMLE (Restricted Maximum Likelihood) to estimate the variance components of models separately.
I was wondering : No matter what optimization algorithm we use (e.g. BFGS, Genetic Algorithm, etc.), as long as we are working with the full likelihood - are we still expected to get a biased estimate of the variance?

Hi: the biasedness of an estimator is only dependent on whether expected value(estimate) = parameter. So, in your case, $E]s^2] = \sigma^2$ or $E[\bar{x}] = \mu$. The particular optimization algorithm one uses is not connected to bias. The algorithm just maximizes the likelihood so, whatever estimates it comes out with are just doing that. In the case of the gaussian, the MLE of $\mu$ happens to be $\bar{x}$ and the MLE of $\sigma^2 = \sigma^2_{MLE}$. But they were the parameter estimates that maximized the likelihood. Whether they are biased or not  needs to be checked using the definition of bias.

One thing I realized after writing above is that terminology can cause confusion. When one refers to $\bar{x}$, that is thought of as an estimator of the mean $\mu$. The actual number ( i.e: the value of $\hat{u}$ that comes out of an optimization procedure) is referred to as the estimate of the mean $\mu$. So, the estimator can be unbiased or biased but that answer is unrelated to the estimate obtained from the optimization.
